# Does using sockets over a LAN introduce any security issues?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm having some trouble understanding the security of sockets. I have some code set up in Python, which looks a bit like this:

server.py:

```py
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234))
s.listen(5)
```

client.py:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1234)
```

I set myself a project to make a VOIP over LAN, or as close as I can get. I'll be using strictly private IP addresses in this program. I read that opening ports can be dangerous, so I'm a little nervous.

As you can see, I am using the port 1234. Could this introduce a vulnerability from any external threats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people say "opening ports can be dangerous" what they mean is that making an application available to connections from an unknown source (such as the Internet) is risky. There may be bugs in the application that allow a remote attacker to execute commands, for example.

As long as you don't accept connections directly from the Internet you're probably fine. If an attacker has access to your LAN, you have more serious things to worry about.